# iPad screen auto resize in swift 5

Tags: ios, swift

I'm not using storyboard for my app. All design I've done programatically. 
Now I'm badly stuck in screen resizing. See my example code for navigation bar:-

```
   let screenSize: CGRect = UIScreen.main.bounds

    screenWidth = screenSize.width
    screenHeight = screenSize.height

    NameHeight = screenHeight * 0.09
    NameWidth = screenWidth
    navBar = UINavigationBar(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 30, width: NameWidth, height: NameHeight))
    self.view.addSubview(navBar)

    navBar.setItems([navItem], animated: false)
```

This navigation bar is perfectly working for both landscape and portrait.
Problem is happening:-

```
1) if I suddenly move my iPad from landscape to portrait or vice versa 
then screen is not properly fit.

2) but if I click any button or anything then screen is properly fit.
```

That means when screen is refreshing then view is good.

My total app code done in this manner.

Are there any solution for my issue?

Does I need to add anything in AppDelegate which will help to reload the screnn??? or any idea please....

Help me please to overcome this issue.....

Comment: "then screen not good", it would help if you provided some screenshots of what happens. Where is that code snippet from? Did you design your app programatically with constraints?

Comment: @Ferdz yes programatically... I'm posting this question through MacBook. that's why not able to post screenshot. I'm trying to give it.

Comment: I asked if you used constraints, you already mentioned you were doing it programatically

Comment: No, I've not added any constraints. I'm not too much experience in ios/swift. Does I need to add constraints for each view and each section?? How to add?

Comment: Status bar's height is 20pt not 30.

Answer (score 0):

I'd have to see the code to know what the exact issue is, but you can try:

```
override func didRotateFromInterfaceOrientation(fromInterfaceOrientation: UIInterfaceOrientation) {

            // Reload Data here

            self.view.setNeedsDisplay()
```

Comment: Thanks for Your answer. I'm trying it.

Answer (score 0):

The below piece of code saved me:-

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)

    if UIDevice.current.orientation.isLandscape {
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }else if UIDevice.current.orientation.isFlat {
        self.viewDidLoad()
    } else {
        self.viewDidLoad()
    }
}
```

May be I did the wrong thing. But it saved me ...